GNU based Shamir Secret Sharing library / utility
I’m looking for a Shamir’s Secret Sharing (SSS) utility or library that is suitable for production use. Are there any GNU implementations or other solutions published by reputable and trusted authors?

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
